# Switch terminal emulators

Tags: terminal

I mainly use st terminal for its fast startup time compared to other terminals. However, sometimes, I find myself in need for better UTF-8 support and want to switch terminal emulator of currently viewed file. What's the best way to achieve this?

This almost works:

```
map <localleader>k :!konsole -e nvim %<CR>
```

but since the original terminal doesn't exit, it shows the file in use. And if I quit before launching the command, vim will complain about `%` having no corresponding opened file.

Comment: Create a session file, quit vim, open up your other terminal, reload the session. Or use a terminal multiplexer and connect to that some tmux/screen session and continue editing

Comment: UTF-8 should work well in `st`; what specifically doesn't work well for you?

Comment: @MartinTournoij Arabic letter shaping